# Как асинхронно ожидать ввод от пользователя?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть страница на этой странице есть хук
js:

```
onAuth() {
    return {
        authCredentials: {username: "username", password: "password"}
    }
};
```

Пример формы для отображения:

```
<form>
    <input id="login">
    <input id="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Как отобразить форму на текущей странице и ожидать ввода логина и пароля, чтобы потом передать в authCredentials?

Comment: А как хук используется? Без контекста сложно понять что можно, а что нет, я бы предложил инитить функцию при сабмите, но может вам это не подходит.

Comment: это не особо важно, onAuth() вызывается внешней библиотекой, при его вызове мне нужно показать форму логина и вернуть введенные данные.

Comment: Так Ярослав верно заметил, чем не подходит вызов он сабмит?

Comment: тем, что onAuth() вызывается не из моего кода, соответственно если повесить обработчик на "submit" то что мы возвращаем в onAuth()?